# SonataUserBundle User entity doesn't map changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I want to make the email field optional. I read that i need to use `@AttributeOverrides` annotation.
My `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User` class:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="gm_user")
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true, unique=false))
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

My `config.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        path:     %database_path%
        types:
          json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name:    main
    user_class:       Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    profile:  # Authentication Form
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:

sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin Panel
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }
        groups:

sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: ~

    templates:
        form:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
        filter:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

            show:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
```

When I'm trying to change schema by `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get:
`Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
Everything works after:

1. Deleting files under `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\` directory
2. Running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`